# Simple Way To Draw Outer Path of Intersecting CGRects in CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgrect, cgpath

Can someone tell me if there's a simple way to get the outer path of a set of intersecting CGRects. So given an array of any number of intersecting CGRects I could get the CGPath tracing the outer edges of all of the rects. Note that I'm not looking for a CGRect that encompasses all the rects, but the multisided path of the outer edges.

[image]